# Best place for json Serde JAR in CDH Hadoop for use with Hive/Hue/MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hue

I'm using **Hive/Hue/MapReduce with a json Serde**. To get this working I have copied the **json_serde.jar** to several lib directories on every cluster node:

- /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib
- /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib
- /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/lib
- /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib
- ...

On every CDH update of the cluster I have to do that again.
Is there a more elegant way where the **distribution of the Serde in the cluster** would be automatic and **resistant to updates**?

Answer (score 4):

If using **HiveServer2** (Default in Cloudera 5.0+) the following configuration will work across your entire cluster without having to copy the jar to each node.

In your **hive-site.xml** config file, or if you're using Cloudera Manager in the "*HiveServer2 Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hive-site.xml*" config box

```
<property>
 <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
 <value>/user/hive/aux_jars/hive-serdes-1.0-snapshot.jar</value>
</property>
```

Then create the directory in your HDFS filesystem (/user/hive/aux_jars) and place the jar file in it. If you are running HUE you can do this part via the web UI, just click on *File Browser* at the top right.

Comment: I am trying to execute the Jdbc statement to set the Property for my serde jar path..which is in hdfs shared by two data nodes, but  its not getting registered    boolean testpropertyTest =stmt.execute("set hive.aux.jars.path=users/JOBDATA/Jars/my-serde-1.1.2.jar"); Please help

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of Hue and if using Beeswax or HiveServer2:

- Beeswax: there is a workaround with the `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1127
- HiveServer2 supports a `hive.aux.jars.path` property in the `hive-site.xml`. HiveServer2 does not support a `.hiverc` and Hue is looking at providing an equivalent at some point: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1066